# Angular promise does not resolve when I want it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, firebase, angular-promise

I am fighting with Angular's promises to let them resolve when I want it. Given my code below, I first want to retrieve the KeyDataFromServer() and only then execute the rest of the commands after all the Keys have been loaded from the server. However, with the setup as below, first the other commands are executed and shown in my view and then when the data is loaded from the server, the server data is included.

What am I doing wrong?

**// controller** (injected $q and KeyGenerationService)

```
$scope.KeyData = null;

  var defer = $q.defer();
  var promise = defer.promise;

  promise
  .then(
    function() {

      var KeyData = {
          Server:           KeyGenerationService.getKeyDataFromServer()
        };

      return KeyData

  })
  .then(
    function(KeyDataFromFunction1) {

      var KeyData = {
          KeyDateGroup:     KeyGenerationService.generateKeyDateGroup(),
          KeyID:            KeyGenerationService.generateKeyID(),
          Server:           KeyDataFromFunction1.Server
      };

      return KeyData

  })
  .then(
    function(KeyDataFromFunction2){

      $scope.KeyData = KeyDataFromFunction2;

  })
  .catch(
    function(error){
      window.alert(error);
    })


  defer.resolve($scope.KeyData)
```

**// factory**

```
.factory('KeyGenerationService', function($q, fbutil) {

        // returns
        return {

            generateKeyDateGroup: function() {

                var today = new Date();
                var d = today;
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                if(dd<10) {
                dd='0'+dd
                } 
                if(mm<10) {
                mm='0'+mm
                } 
                today = yyyy+''+mm+''+ dd;

                return today;

            },

            generateKeyID: function() {

                var d = new Date().getTime();
                var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
                d = Math.floor(d/16);
                return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
                });

                return uuid;

            }

             getKeyDataFromServer: function() {


                return fbutil.syncArray('keys');

            }

        } // return


    }) // .factory KeyGenerationService
```

Comment: can you setup a plunker with relevant data

Comment: `var defer = $q.defer();
  var promise = defer.promise;

  promise
  .then(` This is not really how promises work.. where's the URL for instance? Get/Post request? I suggest you read some of the documentation.

Comment: the fbutil.syncArray('keys'); handles the get/post request, so the function getKeyDataFromServer. I looked at the tutorial at egghead.io

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using promises is slightly incorrect.  Your controller is the one that should receive the promise, however, your async calls are the ones that should generate, resolve, and/or reject them.

The major unknown is what kind of call the `fbutil.syncArray` is.  While it looks like it is a synchronous call judging from the name, get/post requests typically tend to be asynchronous and will return different things.  Therefore, an important question is what does this call return?

To refactor this so that the Service is responsible for creating the promises, you can do this:

```
.factory('KeyGenerationService', function($q, fbutil) {

        // returns
        return {

            // This is a synchronous function and doesn't need promises
            generateKeyDateGroup: function() {

                var today = new Date();
                var d = today;
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                if(dd<10) {
                dd='0'+dd
                } 
                if(mm<10) {
                mm='0'+mm
                } 
                today = yyyy+''+mm+''+ dd;

                return today;

            },

            // This is a synchronous function and doesn't need promises
            generateKeyID: function() {

                var d = new Date().getTime();
                var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
                d = Math.floor(d/16);
                return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
                });

                return uuid;

            }

            // This is likely an asynchronous function and will need to create/return promises
             getKeyDataFromServer: function() {

                var defer = $q.defer();

                // If fbutil.syncArray was synchronous you can use this
                var result = fbutil.syncArray('keys');
                defer.resolve(result);

               // However, I think the fbutil.syncArray should really be asyncronous, which means it would either use a promise itself or use callbacks. If using promises, the following is how it might look:

               //fbutil.syncArray('keys).then(function(result){
               //  defer.resolve(result);
               //});

                return defer.promise 

            }

        } // return


    }) // .factory KeyGenerationService
```

The controller code would be simplified to be:

```
$scope.KeyData = null;

KeyGenerationService.getKeyDataFromServer().then(
    // Success handler
    function(result){
        $scope.KeyData = {
            KeyDateGroup:     KeyGenerationService.generateKeyDateGroup(),
            KeyID:            KeyGenerationService.generateKeyID(),
            Server:           result
        };
    },
    // Error handler
    function(error){
      window.alert(error);
    }
);
```